# Find some data in content SQL database using REGEXP & replace it via SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I've a sql database, there is an table with column 'value', that column contains html code, in this code I want to find file location "templates/images" & replace it.
For find it that wasn't a real problem:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` WHERE `value` REGEXP '(templates\/images)'
```

How to complete the line to replace just this text by something like 'theme/name/img'?

Comment: mysql regexes can only match. they cannot do replacements. At least you can use the mysql regexes to narrow down potential records, but if your replacement gets "complicated", you'll still have to select into client-side code, do the replacement there, then update the db records.

Comment: So it much easier to create something like php script to find - copy - rewrite a good data to the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one-time need, this sounds like something you can do without a regex. Using some database tools, you can do a simple search-and-replace for the actual string "template/images" in your database.

For instance, on Windows, you can do this in HeidiSQL (a free program).

[image: HeidiSQL Replace]

Comment: Thanks but it not really this, on my 'value' colomn i have html code, somthing like:
<p>Some text <img src="template/images/image.jpg"></p>
With your code it's remplaced all content by:
theme/name/img
I need to remplace only the source of all images <img src"...">

Comment: It's great :) i've allready thinked about to use some software for edit sql code, but this database is toooooooo big so text editors and HeidiSQL just crashes after X time of thinking...
That why I want to do it with sql code.
Thank you a lot for the information :) it's work but with crashes, it will take a little bit time to remplace all data

Comment: @suvorovdesign Nothing wrong with writing code! :) Although to do exactly what you want, you might have to access the records via Python, PHP, C#... For GUI tools my favorite is actually SQLYog. I mentioned Heidi because it's free, though SQLyog also has a free community edition. Google "SQLyog tutorial" for a great tut.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've done what I needed :)  SQLyog is mutch faster then HeidiSQL

Comment: @suvorovdesign Yes, feature-rich. If you do a lot of work in MySQL, you will love it. I really miss it when I have to work on OSX, SequelPro doesn't come close.